# Link models cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

[My client has many positions and each position has many shifts.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMbYH.png)

[image]

I need that when I make the client query `$this->Client->find('all')` I return all the jobs and data shifts for each client

```php
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [Client] => Array(
            [id] => 1
            [name] => ALLIANCE
            [date1] => 
            [date2] => 
            [status] => 1
        )
        [Jobs] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [id] => 1
                [client_id] => 1
                [description] => ensamblador
                [date] => 2019-09-22
                [status] => 1
                [created] => 2019-09-22 21:11:23
                [modified] => 2019-09-22 21:11:25
                [user_id] => 1
            )
        )
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [Cliente] => Array(
            [id] => 2
            [nname] => BAXTER
            [date1] => 
            [date2] => 
            [status] => 1
        )
        [Jobs] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [id] => 2
                [client_id] => 2
                [description] => ensamble
                [date] => 2019-09-22
                [status] => 1
                [created] => 2019-09-22 21:32:26
                [modified] => 2019-09-22 21:32:27
                [user_id] => 1
            )
        )
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [Cliente] => Array(
            [id] => 3
            [nombre] => BD CARE FUSION
            [date1] => 
            [date2] => 
            [status] => 1
        )
        [Jobs] => Array()
    )
```

but I don't know what to do to send me the shifts too

Comment: please share your code and structure database tables from which you are fetching data. posting an image will not help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the following code should be enough for your scenario. If you could provide more detail, we can help you better.

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class ClientJob extends AppModel
{

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Client' => array(
            'className' => 'Client',
            'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Shifts' => array(
            'className' => 'ClientJobShift',
            'foreignKey' => 'job_id'
        )
    );
}
```

You can try to check the result using this way

```
$clientJob = this->ClientJob->findById(9999);
echo json_encode($clientJob);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you try to set your ClientJobShift belong to ClientJob

Like this

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel','Model');
class ClientJobShift extends AppModel {


   $this->belongsTo('ClientJob')
        ->setForeignKey('job_id');
}
```